# Reading long attributed value from bluetooth characteristics

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

```
         public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, 
                  didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor 
      service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        if (service.uuid.uuidString == "FFA1") {
            for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
                if (characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "FFF3") {
                    peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
                    print("Found Device Name Characteristic")
                    print("\(characteristic)")
                    if let value = characteristic.value {
                        print("data: \(value as NSData)")
                    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am able to read only 22 bytes of data from the above code. But the peripheral device is sending 128 bytes of data. I wanted to read the 128 bytes data at once instead of reading it by chunks.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how you came up with those `uuid` values; 4 digit values are reserved to be issued by the Bluetooth SIG and those numbers have not been issued. Regardless, you can't access `characteristic.value` immediately after reading. You need to wait for a callback to the [`didUpdateValueFor:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518708-peripheral) delegate method.

Comment: @Paulw11 getting only 22bytes of data from didDpdatevaluefor delegate method also. please let me know if  i need to set any properties to read long data which is more than 22bytes.

Comment: You can't control it from the reading side. The peripheral sends what it sends. If the Bluetooth connection has negotiated a smaller MTU then the peripheral needs to ensure that it sends the data in suitably sized chunks. What version of iOS does your device have?  I see people reported a 20 byte MTU prior to iOS 16.1

Comment: @Paulw11 iOS version is 15.7.1

Comment: Regardless there is nothing to do on the central side.  You need to address it on the peripheral side; Make sure that you do not attempt to send more bytes than can be accommodated by the negotiated MTU

Comment: I could able to read the complete data (250 bytes) on iPhone 6s, but on iPhone 12 pro, 13 and 7 its only reading 22 bytes of data.